# software tracking

Tags: .net, tracking, beta

I have developed a small .NET application and for the BETA I want to add some tracking code so I can monitor the number of times it was installed, how many times it is run and which features are more popular on different operating systems so I can do some A/B testing.

It would be nice to also know the geo location of my users in case usage patterns vary by region.  Are there any plug & play solutions for .NET rather than having to develop a custom solution myself?

Comment: I don't think users will be happy giving you all these information. Host it in Codeplex (gives u number of downloads) it has a defect tracker, discussion board as well for feedback.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.trackerbird.com. With regards to privacy comments, as long as the info is anonymous and you inform your users in the EULA it should not be a big deal. (Disclaimer: I am affiliated with Trackerbird)

Answer (score 1):

Gibralta by Gibraltar Software [LINK](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/) offers what you´re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SoftwareStats](http://www.softwarestats.net)' runtime intelligence solution - offers info on location and all other aspects of usage as well as feature tracking.